# Number of PhraseQuery matches in a document

Tags: lucene, full-text-indexing

This is my code to perform a PhraseQuery using Lucene. While it is clear how to get score matches for each document inside the index, i am not understanding how to extract the total number of matches for a single document.
The following is my code performing the query:

```
        PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();

        builder.add(new Term("contents", "word1"), 0);
        builder.add(new Term("contents", "word2"), 1);
        builder.add(new Term("contents", "word3"), 2);
        builder.setSlop(3);
        PhraseQuery pq = builder.build();

        int hitsPerPage = 10;
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopDocs docs = searcher.search(pq, hitsPerPage);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

        System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");

        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i)
        {
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            System.out.println(docId + " " + hits[i].score);
        }
```

Is there a method to extract the total number of matches for each document rather than the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach A.** This might not be the best way but it will give you a quick insight. You can use `explain()` function of `IndexSearcher` class which will return a string containing lots of information and phrase frequency in a document. Add this code inside your for loop:

```
System.out.println(searcher.explain(pq, searcher.doc(docId)));
```

**Approach B.** A more systematic way of doing this is to do the same thing that `explain()` function does. To compute the phrase frequency, `explain()` builds a `scorer` object for the phrase query and calls `freq()` on it. Most of the methods/classes used to do this are private/protected so I am not sure if you can really use them. However it might be helpful to look at the code of `explain()` in `PhraseWeight` class inside `PhraseQuery` and `ExactPhraseScorer` class. (Some of these classes are not public and you should download the source code to be able to see them).

Comment: I tried the Approach A as first and i obtained a phraseFreq=0.33333334 extracted from the `explain()` function. I was expecting an int as total number of matches.

Comment: it is normalized by value of the slop. As an example, let's say your document is "X Y Z" and you set the slop=2. Then the `phraseFreq` of query "X Y" will be 1, but the `phraseFreq` for the query "X Z" will be 1/2=0.5.